# Yii 2, Sorting Array, ArrayHelper

Tags: arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, yii2

How can i sort an Array like this:

So this works:

```
ArrayHelper::multisort($dataProvider, ['id'], [SORT_DESC]);


foreach ($dataProvider as $teilnahme) {
    ?>
<tr><td><?= Html::a("<time>". Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($teilnahme->durchfuehrung0->datum)."</time>", ['/durchfuehrung/detail/'.$teilnahme->durchfuehrung0->id], ['class'=>'']) ?>

    </td>
    <td><?= Html::a($teilnahme->durchfuehrung0->veranstalter0->name, ['/veranstalter/profil/'.$teilnahme->durchfuehrung0->veranstalter0->id], ['class'=>'']) ?>

    </td>
    <td>
        <?= $teilnahme->durchfuehrung0->veranstalter0->region0->name; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?= $teilnahme->punkte; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
```

But how can i Sort:

```
$teilnahme->durchfuehrung0->datum
```

What i tried:

```
ArrayHelper::multisort($dataProvider,function($item){
    return isset($item->durchfuehrung0['datum']) ? ['id', 'datum'] : 'datum';
},SORT_DESC);
```

but nothing happens here....

Comment: How can i delete my stupid Question

Comment: This is the Solution: Very simpleusort($dataProvider, function($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($b->durchfuehrung0->datum, $a->durchfuehrung0->datum);
});

Answer (score 3):

I tried to find a solution to sort dropDownList with `ArrayHelper::map`.

This is the solution I got for my project:

```
dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(tab_sectors::find()->asArray()->select('Id, Description')->orderBy('Description')->all(), 'Id','Description')
```